# MongoDB update fields of subarrays that meet criteria

Tags: mongodb

I am having a problem where I need to update a specific field found in arrays contained in a bigger array that match certain criteria as of **MongoDB v2.2.3**.

I have the following mongodb sample document.

```php
{
  _id: ObjectId("50be30b64983e5100a000009"),
  user_id: 0
  occupied: {
    Greece: [
      {
        user_id: 3,
        deadline: ISODate("2013-02-08T19:19:28Z"),
        fulfilled: false
      },
      {
        user_id: 4,
        deadline: ISODate("2013-02-16T19:19:28Z"),
        fulfilled: false
      }
    ],
    Italy: [
      {
        user_id: 2,
        deadline: ISODate("2013-02-15T19:19:28Z"),
        fulfilled: false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Each country in the `occupied` array has its own set of arrays.

What I am trying to do is find the document where `user_id` is 0, search through the `occupied.Greece` array only for elements that have `"deadline": {$gt: ISODate(current-date)}` and change their individual "fulfilled" fields to true.

I have tried the `$` and `$elemMatch` operators but they match only one, the first, array element in a query whereas I need it to match **all** eligible elements by the given criteria and make the update without running the same query multiple times or having to process the arrays client-side.

Is there no server-side solution for generic updates in a single document? I am developing using PHP though a solution to this should be universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not possible. From [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/positional/#_S_):

> Remember that the positional `$` operator acts as a placeholder for the **first match** of the update **query selector**. [emphasis not mine]

This is tracked in the MongoDB Jira under [SERVER-1243](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243).

There's quite a number of related feature requests in the jira, mostly under the topic '[virtual collections](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-142)'.

Comment: Was hoping for at least a dirty solution on this one. Thank you for the jira link nevertheless.